# Kinect not getting power from Irobot create base?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having problem while connecting the kinect power using DB25 connector of Irobot create base. The connector circuit is designed by clearpath robotics to provide 12V DC power to kinect by taking power from pin 10 and 14 of DB25 connector of irobot create base.

I read to a tutorial by Prof. Jason O'Kane he says that :
**For the Kinect sensor to operate correctly, it must draw power from the Create’s battery. (The 5V available from the USB connection to the netbook is not sufﬁcient; the Kinect needs at least 8V. Note that seeing blinking lights in the Kinect is, in my experience, not enough to know for sure that the Kinect is receiving the power it needs.)
Your Turtlebot has a cable connecting the Kinect to the Create for this purpose, but by default that power supply is disabled. To enable it .........**

```
rosrun create_node kinect_breaker_enabler.py
```

I tried it but this is not working. The create base is connected to ttyACM0 port as the serial to USB connector definition.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68155/kinect-not-getting-power-from-irobot-create-base?/) by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 205 on 2013-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey If you are using Kinect with turtlebot then you have to move the bot to start kinect. If you move it couple of inches then you'll start receiving data from kinect.

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0